# Entity Validation Error in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on ASP.net MVC ...i have made database and now i am using the code below to insert data in the database using View Model class.
But it gives Entity Validation Error on db.savechanges() in user table(as tbl
_user). Please let me know where i am doing mistake.

**Code to insert in DB**

```
public string RegisterStudent(RegisterationLoginViewModel svm)
    {
        tbl_User_Role usr_role = new tbl_User_Role
        {
           // UserRole_Id=svm.User_Role_id,
            RoleName = svm.User_Role,
            Dsecription=svm.Description,
            OtherDetails=svm.OtherDetails,
        };
        db.tbl_User_Role.Add(usr_role);
        db.SaveChanges();

        tbl_User S_Up = new tbl_User
        {
            FullName = svm.Full_Name,
            DOB = svm.Date_of_Birth,
            Address = svm.Home_Address,
            MobileNumber = svm.Mobile_Number1,
            CNIC = svm.CNIC,
            Country = svm.Country,
            Provience = svm.Provience,
            City = svm.City,
            UserRole_Id = usr_role.UserRole_Id,
            Gender = svm.Gender,
            CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,

        };
        db.tbl_User.Add(S_Up);
        db.SaveChanges(); -->**Exception is thrown at this line**
```

Comment: include the errors.

Comment: Done sir! Error is at last line of the code

Comment: Need to see the error itself, not just that "-->**Exception is thrown at this line**"  A stack trace would be helpful.  My first hunch as to the problem is an fk constraint.

Comment: Include the Model?

Comment: need to see `tbl_User` class. may you are forgeting to initial a not allowed null property or you are using a DataAnnotation Attribute in your Model that don't attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

If your `UserRole_Id` in model `tbl_User_Role` is not auto generated, then writing this line of code `UserRole_Id = usr_role.UserRole_Id` giving `null` because may be it is the Foreign Key of `tbl_User` table.

Beside, If you have set `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` then you need to get it's `UserRole_Id` after saving the `usr_role` and then assign it to `UserRole_Id`.

And finally recheck your Required fields are not null and foreign key is getting value.